# split word from string including space using js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split string including string but space are also spitted.

my code:-

```
var a ='                     that i love          
           game1           ';
console.log(a.split(' '))
```

my current output is like:-

```
(57) ["↵", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "that", "i", "love↵", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "game1↵↵↵", "", "", "", ""]
```

Output that I am trying to get somthing like this:-

```
 (4)["              that",'i','               love','   ↵game'];
```

How can I split string in such a way including space and line break??

### Please don't suggest me idea using jquery

Comment: why is no space around `'i'`?

Comment: I am just showing you example thanks alot for helping me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use String#match with a regular expression ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1izGOZ/1/)) to get something similar to what you want:

```js
var a =`                     that i love          
           game1           `;

console.log(a.match(/\s*\S*/g));
 
// or

console.log(a.match(/\s*\S*\s*/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in `split`.

```js
var a =`                     that i love         
           game1           `;
console.log(a.split(/(\s+\S+\s+)/));
```